# Pattern to initialize an EJB that depends on another application EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, architecture, ejb-3.1

How should I initialize an EJB when it depends on another application that is located in another cluster that is still not started?

How should I do it?

- **@PostConstruct**: Maybe I can loop until the dependant EJB is available, but I'm afraid it would timeout or block the server loading process.
- **@Schedule**: Maybe scheduling the initialization process to avoid blocks on server and then service requests only if init is done, otherwise throw an error.

How do you think should I proceed? Would you recommend me some Pattern?

Comment: Make PostConstruct in one of application on second server. When second server is getting started, then invoke RMI (Remote EJB) and initialize from that EJB

Comment: @ashokhein That could be! However, the application 2 does not have to know about the application 1. That would generate a coupling and a cyclic dependency I would like to avoid. Thank you anyway.

Comment: How could be cycle dependency. because it is one way direction. applicaiton 2 ---> application 1

Comment: @ashokhein I see it like: application2 --> application 1 (init) --> application 2.  However, the application2 is actually a "gateway", so it acts tunneling requests. The requirement for app2 is that is shouldn't have dependencies on it's clients.

Comment: I agree with this :)

Comment: I assume that your first (A) application is not usable till the second (B) is fully started. Then I'd say there is no point to start A till B is ready, so I'd keep it as stopped by default. To avoid strong coupling, I'd probably create third app - a starter (S), which would monitor, if B is ready, and if it is, then it would start A.

Comment: Is the dependent EJB initialised as part of it's application start up? Or does it happen as a consequence of some kind of service request?

Comment: @Gas Having a 3rd app to monitor A/B state could be!  The application A and B should be always started however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the above suggestions are valid, I think. It's a matter of the circumstances around your problem, I think.

Depending on whether or not you can independently start A, you can use a third element like Gas suggested to guarantee that A does not come up (and fail or gets stuck) if B is not ready.

If on the other hand, A starts automatically and you cannot change that, then it depends on whether or not you can control when the initalization process happens. If you, schedule the initialization of the entire dependency chain and it should work, but if you don't know or can't control when B comes online and A will start no matter what, then there's no choice but to poll until B is up.

Personally, I've seen polling not be so bad as long as what you're waiting for is avaliable starts fast or recovers quickly in case of failure.

On another note, can you not control how the clusters start via their configuration? You could avoid the problem if you make the second application's cluster always start first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I dont know if the real problem is underlying infrastructure (no clustering for the B app), or the Infrastucture guys executing the clusters restarts.  Anyway, as you say, I think polling would be the best solution for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you manage to solve the initialization of the EJB, you will end up creating dependencies. Architecturally speaking, initialization dependency will undo the reason it was decided to split up App#1 (gateway) and App#2 (service host).

**Alternative suggestion** is to keep them independent, as they are currently, and instead rely on exception handling. 
If the service in App#2 is unreachable, you can choose to throw a custom exception like "Service not available, please try later" or, depending on the need, pool the requests to be executed when the service is available again.

This also protects you against the failure of App#2 after start up, for e.x. if it is down for maintenance or unresponsive due to some internal errors.